# jQuery Detect iPad, change font-size of element

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, detect, addclass

I need to change the font-size of some elements if the user is on the iPad because the iPad renders my navigation bar off screen (due to some unknown font enlargement on iPads).

Here is my current CSS:

```
#mainmenu ul li a{
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:38px;    
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   float: left;
}
```

I want the font-size to be changed to .9em if user is on iPad, so I could either use the .attr or the .addClass, doesn't matter to me, I just dont know how to get to that point, something like this I presume?

```
function isiPad(){
    return (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1);
}

$(function() {
    if ($(isiPad).length == 1) {
  do something }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had success with this:

```
function isiPad() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i); 
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the 'THEN' code for it?  I'm assuming there is no need to put 'IF'...

Comment: @ToddN: With this function defined you can just use it in your code "if (isiPad()) { ... do iPad-y stuff here ... }